# freopen returning errno 14 EFAULT : while executing. (arm , linux, android)

Tags: android, c, linux, arm, freopen

freopen returning errno 14 : which is equivalent to EFAULT - BAD ADDRESS
Cross Compiled on Ubuntu .
Executed on arm based android device 
Kernel 3.0.23 perf

```
 ELF 32-bit LSB  executable, ARM, EABI5 version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), not stripped
```

Code :

```
if (!freopen(NULL, "rb", stdin)) {
        return errno;
  }
```

Comment: This seems to be missing an actual question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the first parameter of `freopen()` should be a path name. If you pass that as `NULL`, that's obviously asking for trouble.

What do you want to achieve?

Comment: According to POSIX, a null filename means to change the mode of the existing stream, [which may or may not be supported](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/freopen.html).

Comment: I wants to reopen stdin in binary mode. but when i uses freopen and compiles for my arm machine using arm-linux-androideabi-gcc. Program stop executing and returns an errno 14.   But on my ubuntu machine it works perfectly as i wants.

Comment: Actually, it's in the C99 standard as well, so it's definitely a valid way to _call_ `freopen`, even if you can't expect it to succeed. The above code works (or at least gives no error and returns the same stdin pointer) with glibc on my desktop machine despite not being in my manpage either. Indeed the [glibc source](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=libio/freopen.c;h=91cde193ee3cbe8ef4ab9fcfff96d4a15b7e3dd3;hb=HEAD#l50) confirms it, however [bionic is not glibc](http://code.metager.de/source/xref/android/4.2/bionic/libc/stdio/freopen.c)...